# Ambari sandbox : elasticsearch port 9200 cannot reach

Tags: elasticsearch, sandbox, ambari

I have started the Ambari Sandbox ( actual IP is 13.82.183.171 ).
I have started also elasticsearch on one terminal session.
If I open another terminal session , YES I can access to elasticsearch with CURL : curl -X GET http://localhost:9200

BUT If I put the http://localhost:9200  or http://127.0.0.1:9200  directly in IE , it cannot reach it.

I tried :
1) modifying the elasticsearch.yml with network.host: 13.82.183.171 But elastic search then don´t start.

I think I have to open the port 9200 on ambari Sandbox, but don´t know how to do this

Thank You -

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it may be permission settings. Is your Elasticsearch using readonlyrest(readonlyrest.yml)? and if it is configured correctly?

Comment: I don´t have this file in the Elasticsearc/config dir

Comment: But maybe  I didn´t explain well my problem. I just would like to have access to elasticsearch (http://127.0.0.1:9200 )   from my laptop.  My steps until now are  1) start azure  sandbox ambari 2) open a Web Client http://13.82.183.171:4200 3) download and start elasticsearch from client 4) from another terminal, client, Yes I can see eleasticsearch UP with the Curl command 5) would like to access elastic search from IE but HERE is my problem , does not find the URL with port 9200

Comment: Then  I think what I have to do is to put a rule on the port 9200 in the virtual box , But cannot see how to do this in Ambari Azure